# Перетаскиваемая панель

Tags: winforms, .net, c#

Как создать перетаскиваемую панель, как панель инструментов в Visual Studio?

Есть ли какие-то стандартные методы?

Answer (score 1):

Если я не ошибаюсь, стандартные ToolStrip/ToolStripPanel не допускают перетаскивание и стыковку. Но есть приличная библиотека [DockPanel Suite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/), которая подходит близко по возможностям к панелям Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Мы используем DevExpress DockManager, но я бы сказал, что это самый глючный из используемых нами их компонентов. Интересно, что используют сами Microsoft - у них-то они работают хорошо и стабильно.